# Login page keeps trying to authenticate with social-login instead of entered credentials

Tags: bug, login

##### Summary

On login page, login with credentials keeps trying to login with social integration if you previously tapped on one of social-login buttons, and hit back button.

##### Steps to reproduce

1. Go to https://stackoverflow.com/
2. Tap on Login button (top-right)
3. On Stack Overflow Login page, tap on "Log in with Google" button.
4. On Google Login page, hit back button from your browser.
5. On Stack Overflow Login page, fill in your email and password.
6. Tap on "Log in" button below password input-field.
7. You will be taken to Google Login page. (bug)

##### Expected

Login succeeds/fails based on entered credentials.

##### More

1. Issue is reproducible with other social login integrations.
2. I am using Firefox v99.0.1

Comment: I can confirm that this also happens on Chrome latest (Version 100). And I'm not sure why this gets downvoted.

Comment: It looks to me like this issue is based on a hidden form element carrying the used oauth server which is set when clicking on "log in with xyz", but not reset and going back to the page.